# How to activate python virtual environment in init file?

Tags: init-file, python, start-up, environment

How would I activate a specific `virtual environment` in my `init file`? I know how to activate it manually, but I don't like to do it every time I start emacs.

To activate it manually I used:

```
pyvenv-activate
```

Then a `path` needs to be specified and it works. So I tried the following in the init file:

```
(pyvenv-activate PATH_TO_VENV)
```

Unfortunately it tells me:

```
Invalid function: (quote pyvenv-activate)
```

I want to do this, because without activating the `venv`, `elpy` does not find it and thus doesn't find `jedi` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load `pyvenv` first and then activate env. Add this to your init file.

```
(require 'pyvenv)
(pyvenv-activate "~/.virtualenvs/exp/")
```

If you are using virtualenvwrapper, you can use `pyvenv-workon`

```
(require 'pyvenv)
(pyvenv-workon "exp")
```

If you load `elpy` first, it will automatically load `pyvenv`. You don't need to do `(require 'pyvenv)`.

Comment: Does it load pyvenv twice, if I still add the require statement, or does it realize, that the dependency is already fulfilled? I tend to keep the require, just in case I move it around in my init file some day…

Comment: require checks before loading features. So it should load only once.

Comment: How could I verify that pyvenv is successfully loaded  `venv`?